# How to track clicks on an element that isn't a link nor a button using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I need to track clicks on an element that is neither a link nor a button, using Google Tag Manager. I've been able to track links and buttons without any problem, but I can't seem to track these elements.

In the image below I have a `ul`that contains several `li`. I want to track cliks on the `li`elements. Each `li` has `class="producto-destacado"` This is the code:

```
<ul class="react-multi-carousel-track">
    <li class="producto-destacado">Content</li>
    <li class="producto-destacado">Content</li>
    <li class="producto-destacado">Content</li>
    <li class="producto-destacado">Content</li>
</ul>
```

(You can view the actual site [here](http://www.reebit.cl))

[image]

The way I'm tagging now is by creating a trigger of type "All elements > some clicks" and then "Click element > matches CSS selector > .producto-destacado

I've also tried with "All elements > some clicks" and then "Click ID > Equals > .producto-destacado" and not results either.

[image]

*I've also tried the solution [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121466/google-tag-manager-not-tracking-links-clicks-on-images-and-icons), didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the `.` in front of `producto-destacado`

Try:

`Click Classes` `equals` `producto-destacado`

[image]

Comment: You're right. Should be ```equals``` updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to wrap my `<li>` tags in `<a>`tags. That worked for me. Hope this will help someone.